# How to translate this to "inline CSS"?

Tags: html, css

I am reading the following about how to make a responsive table in HTML

[HTML Responsive Table using CSS](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/responsive-tables-using-css-div-tag/)

But I am struggling how to convert this CSS to inline CSS since I am using a third party product that dont allow a separate CSS file so I need to do the styling "inline"

Comment: simple do a bunch of copy/paste

Comment: So you mean I can use the same commands directly in the HTML? but there is no ID to tie it to then?

Comment: Remove whitespace, copy rules, paste into `style` attribute, done. If you need media queries you're out of luck though.

Comment: ok you seems to don't know how inline CSS works :) so i simply advice to take 5 min to see how it works

Comment: Yes I am hunting for a good doc but I cant find any good ones that describes that but I can find plenty around how to use separate CSS

Comment: simply because the correct way is to use separate CSS ... and whataver your project is and whataver your are using you are able to add external CSS even if it's not using external file, you can simply add it before your HTML

Answer (score -1):

Just write a  tag inside  tag and copy the content from CSS file to the html file. It will work.